# Lexicographically smallest binary string after at most K adjacent swaps

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, greedy

I attempted the question on codeforces but it is failing the test case 2.

*The question is :*

You are given a binary string of length n (i. e. a string consisting of n characters '0' and '1').

In one move you can swap two adjacent characters of the string. What is the lexicographically minimum possible string you can obtain from the given one if you can perform no more than k moves? It is possible that you do not perform any moves at all.

Note that you can swap the same pair of adjacent characters with indices i and i+1 arbitrary (possibly, zero) number of times. Each such swap is considered a separate move.

You have to answer q independent test cases.

**Input**

The first line of the input contains one integer q — the number of test cases.

The first line of the test case contains two integers n and k — the length of the string and the number of moves you can perform.

The second line of the test case contains one string consisting of n characters '0' and '1'.

**Output**

For each test case, print the answer on it: the lexicographically minimum possible string of length n you can obtain from the given one if you can perform no more than k moves.

Site : https://codeforces.com/contest/1256/problem/D

My approach :

I iterate the string from the second index and whenever I encounter '10' , I do a swap and then iterate again through the second index.

My Code :

```
q = int(input())
for i in range(q):
[n,k] = list(map(int,input().split(" ")))
s = list(map(int, list(input())))
a = 0
j = 1

while(a < k and j < n-1):
    if(s[j] == 1 and s[j+1] == 0):
        s[j] = 0
        s[j+1] =1
        a += 1
        j = 1

    elif(s[j-1] == 1 and s[j] == 0): #This checks the occruence of the pattern '101' which is formed 
        s[j-1] = 0                   # after the swapping of the pattern '110'
        s[j] = 1
        a += 1
        j = 1
    else:
        j += 1

s = list(map(str,s))
s = "".join(s)
print(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

The lexigraphically minimal binary string has all zeros on the left. As we iterate from the left, we move a zero as far as possible, keeping track of how many 1's are to the left and how many swaps are available. For example,

```
11011010, 5 swaps

Arrive at first 0:
5 swaps, 2 1's
Output 0
swaps = swaps - 2

Arrive at second 0:
3 swaps, 2 + 2 = 4 1's
Output 10111
swaps = swaps - 3

No more swaps available,
so output the rest of the string:

0 + 10111 + 10 =
01011110
```